# Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0

Tags: sql-server, sqlconnection, sqlcommand, sqlcmd

I launched Command Prompt and at the : C:\Windows\system32>sqlcmd -S.\mySQLServer -i"C:\MyFolder\load-Client.sql"

I kept getting this error:

[image: Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0]

Any help is much appreciated. If I use SQL Server Management Studio, it works fine.

Comment: I tried sqlcmd -S serverName\sqlServerInstanceName and I still receive the same error. However, if I type in sqlcmd and nothing else then I able to connect to the sql server.

Comment: Do you have a space between -S and your server/instance name? Same thing for -i and your input file name.